# When passing in this as a parameter into a class, says context required found empty

Tags: android, kotlin

For my code I am passing in this for the context. This is in *mainActivity.kt* file

[image]
This is the error I am getting in my constructor I am calling it like this

```
class ForecastAdapter(val forecast: Forecast, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastData>(){
```

and then I am passing it in the class like this:

```
runOnUiThread {
   view.adapter = ForecastAdapter(weather, this)
}
```

So I have no idea why this isn't working for context. I am new to Kotlin and new to android dev so I am little confused right now.

Comment: That's because this is not the activity/fragment inside the runOnUiThread block. Use `this@MyActivity`

Comment: can you try passing 'this@MainActivity'?

Comment: I did and it did work! But why passing `this@MainActivity` works?

Comment: because `this` always refers to the object of the block you are currently in. You can't see it because kotlin lambda magic hides it, but you pass an anonymous class with one implemented function to runOnUiThread. `this` refers to that

Comment: very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617361/runonuithread-is-not-calling the `this` inside the `{}` is actually a `Runnable` as you can see in the answer there

Comment: Could you post all your ForecastAdapter's constructor and you MainActivity.kt's code?I've tried the same situation and I found that 'this' was worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing is called [SAM Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). Basically you're implementing a `Runnable` within your `{}` block. Therefore `this` refers to the inner class and to access the outer class you have to add the outer [qualified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified) scope `this@MainActivity` to it.

```
runOnUiThread { view.adapter = ForecastAdapter(weather, this@MainActivity) }
```

This is actually the same as

```
val runnable = Runnable { view.adapter = ForecastAdapter(weather, this@MainActivity) }
runOnUiThread(runnable)
```